# Access private class from UITableView/UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, right-to-left

For some RTL purpose, I need to adjust the frame of some subviews like '`_UITableViewCellSeparatorView`' in  `UITableViewCell` and '`UITableViewIndex`' in `UITableView`.

Here is my code:

```
for (UIView *view in [self subviews]) {
            // separator view
            if ([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UITableViewCellSeparatorView")]) {
                CGRect frame = view.frame;
                frame.origin.x = 0;
                view.frame = frame;
            }
        }

if ([self.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
            UITableView* tableView = (UITableView*)self.superview;
            UIView* indexView = [[tableView subviews] lastObject];

            if ([indexView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITableViewIndex")]) {

                indexViewWidth = indexView.frame.size.width;
            }                
        }
```

I wonder whether these changes will be passed by Apple review team?
I only know that we must not use or call private APIs.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the release of iOS 9 and full RTL support, workarounds like this should no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Using of private API is not authorized.

From Apple Review Guide :

> 2.5 Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected

So it may pass one time but it's not a garantie, I advice you to not use private APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I did it some times to workaround some issues of `UIAlertView` and `UINavigationBar` before, it's OK. Things even like method swizzling are also legal.

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted some apps accessing to several private methods and it was fine in the review process, but when Apple introduced iOS 8, most of the methods changed and I had to get rid of them. So, it's fine, but not recommended

Answer (score -1):

*modified*

First of all it's possible that **Apple don't accept your App** (as you can see in Guidelines, they don't accept private API access) or they accept It and in an update or new release they refuse It.
If they accepted your App (I have published some Apps with similar code) in a future OS release this identifiers or not public classes (that you found using introspection) coul be changed by Apple and  It could make your App not work properly